# How to have control over jquery validate error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 fields and using jquery validate for error messages.

When I enter invalid value in the `input` box to the left side, the error messages appear to the immediate right thereby disturbing the alignment of the right side field and vice versa.

What I want is that error messages, instead appear on next line without disturbing the alignment of any static elements.

I am not sure which css classes would be helpful in this case to have control over error messages

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taka1v40/1/)

Here is my HTML:

```
 <form  id="ethernetForm">
 <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv4Address_0">IPv4 Address</label>
        <input class="ipv4editable" type="text" name="ipv4Address" id="ipv4Address_0">
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv6Address_0">IPv6 Address/Mask</label>
        <input class="ipv6editable" type="text" name="ipv6Address" id="ipv6Address_0">
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv4Mask_0">Subnet Mask v4</label>
        <input class="ipv4editable" type="text" name="ipv4Mask" id="ipv4Mask_0">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv4Gateway_0">Gateway v4</label>
        <input class="ipv4editable" type="text" name="ipv4Gateway" id="ipv4Gateway_0">
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv6Gateway_0">Gateway v6</label>
        <input class="ipv6editable" type="text" name="ipv6Gateway" id="ipv6Gateway_0">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error messages show in `label` which is an inline element, so make it a block level, with setting `display:block`

```js
  $("#ethernetForm").validate({

    rules: {
      ipv4Address: {
        ipv4validate: true
      },
      ipv4Mask: {
        ipv4validate: true
      },
      ipv4Gateway: {
        ipv4validate: true
      },
      ipv6Address: {
        ipv6validate: true
      },
      ipv6Mask: {
        ipv6validate: true
      },
      ipv6Gateway: {
        ipv6validate: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      ipv4Address: "Please enter a valid IPv4 address",
      ipv4Mask: "Please enter valid v4 mask",
      ipv4Gateway: "Please enter valid v4 gateway",
      ipv6Address: "Please enter a valid IPv6 address",
      ipv6Mask: "Please enter valid v6 mask",
      ipv6Gateway: "Please enter valid v6 gateway"
    }
  });

  //Validate the IP addresses
  $.validator.addMethod("ipv4validate", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)$/i.test(value);
  });

  $.validator.addMethod("ipv6validate", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:)?[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}:([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}((\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b)\.){3}(\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5}:((\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b)\.){3}(\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b))|(::([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5}((\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b)\.){3}(\b((25[0-5])|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(\d{1,2}))\b))|([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}::([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(::([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1,7}:))$/i.test(value);
  });
```

```css
label.error {
  padding-bottom: -20px;
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="ethernetForm">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv4Address_0">IPv4 Address</label>
        <input class="ipv4editable" type="text" name="ipv4Address" id="ipv4Address_0">
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv6Address_0">IPv6 Address/Mask</label>
        <input class="ipv6editable" type="text" name="ipv6Address" id="ipv6Address_0">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv4Mask_0">Subnet Mask v4</label>
        <input class="ipv4editable" type="text" name="ipv4Mask" id="ipv4Mask_0">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv4Gateway_0">Gateway v4</label>
        <input class="ipv4editable" type="text" name="ipv4Gateway" id="ipv4Gateway_0">
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv6Gateway_0">Gateway v6</label>
        <input class="ipv6editable" type="text" name="ipv6Gateway" id="ipv6Gateway_0">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: that was it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Messages are marked by .error class. Use it to controll them.
https://jsfiddle.net/1s2nvp6r/ - example fiddle.

```
.error{
  position: absolute;
}
```

Also, you can use HTML-inspector build-in in most of modern browsers to check attributes of divs.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

CSS:

```
#ipv4Address_0-error{
   position: absolute ;
   margin-left: -200px ;
   color: #fff ;
   background-color: #222 ;
   padding: 3px ;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click","#ipv4Address_0-error",function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```